# Autocomplete textbox array converting to string in php and saving the selected item of autocomplete to MySql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

Please help me,
I have a autocomplete textbox, which is populated from the database, now i have to save the selected item from the autocomplete into the Mysql database...

Here is my autocomplete textbox:

```
<input type='text' id='anameid' class="form-control" name='aname[]' placeholder="Agent Name" />
```

and

```
<?php
if($_GET['type'] == 'agentname'){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT aname FROM ifcandetails7 where aname LIKE '".strtoupper($_GET['name_startsWith'])."%'");
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
array_push($data, $row['aname']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
}

if($_GET['type'] == 'agentname_table1'){
$row_num = $_GET['row_num'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT aname, anamecpy, amnumber, alnumber, aemail, aaddress, astate, adist, atown, anamecpycpy FROM ifcandetails7 where aname LIKE '".strtoupper($_GET['name_startsWith'])."%'");
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$name = $row['aname'].'|'.$row['anamecpy'].'|'.$row['anamecpy'].'|'.$row['amnumber'].'|'.$row['alnumber'].'|'.$row['aemail'].'|'.$row['aaddress'].'|'.$row['astate'].'|'.$row['adist'].'|'.$row['atown'].'|'.$row['anamecpycpy'].'|'.$row_num;
array_push($data, $name);
}
echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

js for autocomplete

```
$('#agent_detials').autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'ajax.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                       name_startsWith: request.term,
                       type: 'agentname'
                    },
                     success: function( data ) {
                         response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item,
                                value: item
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            autoFocus: true,
            minLength: 0        
          });

                $('#anameid').autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : 'ajax.php',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                           name_startsWith: request.term,
                           type: 'agentname_table1',
                           row_num : 1
                        },
                         success: function( data ) {
                             response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                var code = item.split("|");
                                return {
                                    label: code[0],
                                    value: code[0],
                                    data : item
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                autoFocus: true,            
                minLength: 0,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
                    console.log(names[1], names[2], names[3], names[4], names[5], names[6], names[7], names[8], names[9], names[10]);
            $('#anameid').val(names[1]);
                    $('#anamecpyid').val(names[2]);
                    $('#amnumberid').val(names[3]);
                    $('#alnumberid').val(names[4]);
                    $('#aemailid').val(names[5]);
                    $('#aaddressid').val(names[6]);
                    $('#astateid').val(names[7]);
                    $('#adistid').val(names[8]);
                    $('#atownid').val(names[9]);
                    $('#anamecpycpyid').val(names[10]);
                }               
              });
```

MySql Query:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if(isset($_POST['misbtn'])){
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con){
die("Can not connect : " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("inputfields",$con);
$sql = "INSERT INTO mainsheetinfo (aname) VALUES ('$_POST[aname]')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
mysql_close($con);
}
}
?>
```

Error Msg:
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project12\mis.php on line 15

Comment: First of all mysql_query is deprecated, you should use SQLi or PDO.

Comment: Which bit of code is mis.php?

Comment: mis.php is Mysql Query file, from this file i am trying to insert the data to db.